# How to halt training process at some epoch after which the loss is not improving?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I'm trying to implement logistic regression in python, I want to halt the training process at the epoch beyond which the train and test error are not improving. I did the following:

```
def train(X_train,y_train,X_test,y_test,epochs,alpha,eta0):
    N = len(X_train)
    dim = X_train[0]
    w,b = initialize_weights(dim)
    for i in tqdm(range(epochs)):
        for x,y in zip(X_train,y_train):
            dw = gradient_dw(x,y,w,b,alpha,1)
            db = gradient_db(x,y,w,b)
            w = w + (eta0*dw)
            b = b + (eta0*db)
            
        train_prob=[sigmoid((np.dot(w.T,x))+b) for x in X_train]
        train_loss=logloss(y_train,train_prob)
        test_prob=[sigmoid((np.dot(w.T,x))+b) for x in X_test]
        test_loss=logloss(y_test,test_prob)
        
    return w,b,train_loss,test_loss
```

I am able to get the losses at the end but i wish to stop at the epoch beyond which loss doesn't improve.
Here initialize_weights(), gradient_dw(), gradient_dw(), sigmoid(), logloss() are defined methods.